# Send email from the <> null sender address

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, smtp

```
Send-MailMessage
 -From "from@example.com"
 -To "to@example.com"
 -Subject "Subject" `
 -SmtpServer "localhost" -Body "Test Message"
```

I'm sending email using [Send-MailMessage](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849925.aspx), the powershell equivalent of using System.Net.Mail.MailMessage.

Is there any way of sending email from the null sender address? If not are there any powershell/.NET alternatives I can use.

From is required so cannot be omitted. null, "" etc aren't acceptable because Send-MailMessage validates the from is an email address.

---

[<> Null sender address](http://utcc.utoronto.ca/usg/technotes/smtp-intro.html): *"The sender address is the email address that will receive email about delivery problems (mailing lists change this but not the From: email header so that they, and not the people sending to them, get messages about delivery problems). A special null sender address (MAIL FROM:<>) is used to signal that no one cares and no bounce notifications should be sent. Null senders are used when sending bounce messages themselves, and sometimes at other times."*

Comment: Why would you want to send a mail from a "null" sender?

Comment: My code deals with emails. I can get mail from this address, so I need to be able to test it.

Comment: why not just use Send-MailMessage to send an email you know is going to generate an NDR? Use the From: address to route the bounce to your script.

Comment: @mjolinor interesting idea. May be a bit fragile for testing, but I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with SmtpClient and MailMessage, so using this or Send-MailMessage is out of the question.  Unfortunately that means you're left with either finding a third party library which does support it, or writing the code yourself to send directly through SMTP.

You're probably better off testing this part of your system with a unit test.

Answer (score 0):

## Manually with telnet

```
open localhost 25

HELO Foo
MAIL FROM: <>   <--- the null address
```

## Automated.

Not actually the complete working code, but should give the general impression GetFile and SmtpStream are streams. The solution is to feed an pre-created .eml file by directly interacting with the SMTP protocol.

```
        GivenAClientIsConnectedToAnAgentInTheWAITINGState();

        SmtpStream.WriteAsciiString("MAIL FROM:<>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
        SmtpStream.ReceiveAsAsciiString();

        SmtpStream.WriteAsciiString("RCPT TO:<{0}>{1}",mailboxAddress, Environment.NewLine);
        SmtpStream.ReceiveAsAsciiString();

        SmtpStream.WriteAsciiString("DATA{0}", Environment.NewLine);
        SmtpStream.ReceiveAsAsciiString();
        SmtpStream.SendEmail(_fileRepository.GetFile("NullSenderMessage.eml"));
        SmtpStream.SendDataTerminator();
        SmtpStream.ReceiveAsAsciiString();
        SmtpStream.WriteAsciiString("QUIT");
```